# Port forwarding for torrent client via UPnP

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding

First, I'm currently connected to my neighbor's router who is not at home, which is why I can't ask him to forward a port via the router. I'm trying to forward a port to accept incoming connections for qBittorrent (with UPnP option enabled) on Ubuntu. This already works on Windows where qBittorrent is whitelisted in Windows firewall, and I can change the port in qBittorent and canyouseeme.org then shows that the port is open.

Now, I'm trying to get this work on Ubuntu and this is how ufw is set up:

```
sudo ufw status

Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                DENY        Anywhere                  
53098                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           DENY        Anywhere (v6)             
53098 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

netstat -tap | grep LISTEN | grep qbittorrent

tcp    0    0 *:53098      *:*    LISTEN   1703/qbittorrent
tcp6   0    0 [::]:53098   [::]:* LISTEN   1703/qbittorrent
```

When I check port 53098 on canyouseeme.org it says that the port is closed. What should I do next to get this to work?

Comment: does it work if you completely disable ufw ? If it works on windows then it is not a router UPnP issue.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work after I disable ufw.